# Implement web Service in my Architecture

Tags: c#, web-services, design-patterns, architecture

I'm really really new to programming with an architecture, so I hope someone here can help me.

I have a solution on C# .Net with the next architecture:

- **Data**: Contains the UoW, Repositories, Entity Framework mapping and context.
- **Design**: It'll contain the WPF and Web projects.
- **Domain**: Contains entities that all the other projects will be using.
- **Service**: HERE IS MY PROBLEM!! I have no idea what to do here.

I need to implement a web service that will be consumed by WPF and WEB projects but I don´t know if it really goes here and how it needs to be (Web API or WCF).

Answer (score 1):

A Service in this case is a layer in your application that supports the higher layers with methods to communicate with the underlying layers (Data). You should read up on design patterns in general and in particular [Service Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648490.aspx) and [Repository Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx). You should educate yourself on the differences between WCF  and WebAPI  where the first is XML based and the latter is a RESTful API that I would recommend from modernity perspective if you can choose what to implement.

- [Web API](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/659131/Understanding-and-Implementing-ASPNET-WebAPI).
- [WCF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/566691/WCF-From-a-Beginners-perspective-a-Tutorial)

Comment: I can't understand yet, My repository has to feed my web service? Or the web service has to privide the data for my repo?

Comment: I think both of them. Think in your service as an interface to other modules, other clients... So, if you are going to use just WPF I'd suggest you to use WCF but if you plan to allow other platforms to use your CRUD services (Create Read Update or Delete operations) I'd use a web API.

And also, in order to separate concerns, you should not include your "Desing" (I preffer Presentation) in that solution because that Design project is going to be coupled to your server...